# Geting an UIImage from an UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

Currently I am working on a camera based app. I the camera image inside of a UIImageView to make it easier to manipulate. Now I want to add some effect from the core imaging. Can I somehow get a image out of the view.

This is how I add a effect but it works only for images.

```
NSString *filePath =
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IpadIcon" ofType:@"png"];
NSURL *fileNameAndPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

CIImage *beginImage =
[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:fileNameAndPath];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

CGImageRef cgimg =
[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

[captureImage setImage:newImg];
```

**Getting the Image**

```
- (void) capImage { //method to capture image from AVCaptureSession video feed
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {

        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {

            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }


    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
            [self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: I have a picture inside UIImageView. Now i need to get it out. Is it possible ?

Comment: `UIImage *theImage = imageView.image;`??

Comment: i fell so stupid now. Can u write down that in an awnser so i can give u credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the image using UIImageView's `image` property:

`UIImage *theImage = imageView.image;`